# Retain a CTFrameRef property using ARC

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, core-text

Using ARC, how can I make sure a `CTFrameRef` property is not deallocated ? I am currently using an `assign` property, which is obviously not doing what I want

---

**edit:** my solution based on @KevinBallard answer :

```
- (void)setCoreTextFrame:(CTFrameRef)coreTextFrame
{
    _coreTextFrame = CFRetain(coreTextFrame);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    CFRelease(_coreTextFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTFrameRef` isn't an obj-c object. It follows the CoreFoundation memory management rules, so you can retain it with `CFRetain()` and release it with `CFRelease()`.

So basically, your code dealing with `CTFrameRef` will look identical to non-ARC code.

Comment: thanks ! I edited my question, let me know if there is a better way

Comment: @ThomasJoulin: Your solution is fine, except you're not freeing the old value of `_coreTextFrame` in the setter. You should do something like `CFRetain(coreTextFrame); if(_coreTextFrame) CFRelease(_coreTextFrame); _coreTextFrame = coreTextFrame` (in case the parameter is the current value). And in `-dealloc` you should ensure `_coreTextFrame` is non-`NULL` before releasing it, because `CFRelease(NULL)` will crash.